# How to make JUnit tests in JSF application

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, junit

I want to create some JUnit tests during build time. How I can connect JSF application to database and make test SQL queries to test the code? As far as I can see in Netbeans simple tests can be done on pure Java code. Much of my code are SQL queries which must be tested for proper results.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a separate DAO layer which has sql-queries and doesn't depend on JSF, in this case you could isolate the tests to test only SQL queries. Then you could do the tests for the plain java classes which produce and execute SQL. I could recommend an embedded database and the liquibase (or similar) to fill test schema and data presets.

Comment: The managed beans use `@Resource(name = "jdbc/Oracle") private DataSource ds;` to call Oracle from Glassfish. Can I somehow configure it to call my second datasource which will use DAO?

Comment: In unit tests the @Resource won't work and you will have to manually set the corresponding property. In you tests you could either use an in-memory database to simulate data access or you could create mocks for the DataSource. I would go with the first approach. It's not that hard

Comment: @PeterPenzov The `@Resource` could be injected manually or you could use an IoC container such as the Guice or the Spring-test. It is lightweight so that it is easy to prepare an environment during test set-up.